# Reading raw byte array into std::string

Tags: c++, string

I've been wondering about the following issue: assume I have a C style function that reads raw data into a buffer

```
int recv_n(int handle, void* buf, size_t len);
```

Can I read the data directly into an `std:string` or `stringstream` without allocating any temporal buffers? For example,

```
std::string s(100, '\0');
recv_n(handle, s.data(), 100);
```

I guess this solution has an undefined outcome, because, afaik, `string::c_str` and `string::data` might return a temporal location and not necessarily return the pointer to the real place in the memory, used by the object to store the data.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not use a `vector<char>` instead of a `string`? That way you can do:

```
vector<char> v(100, '\0');
recv_n(handle, &v[0], 100);
```

This seems more idiomatic to me, especially since you aren't using it as a string (you say it's raw data).

Comment: C++11: recv_n(handle, v.data(), 100);

Comment: @Chinasaur: I think a cast is required there, because of the `const`.

Comment: Confusingly, vector::data() is not const but string::data() is.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, after C++11.

But you cant use `s.data()` as it returns a `char const*`

Try:

```
std::string s(100, '\0');
recv_n(handle, &s[0], 100);
```

Depending on situation, I may have chosen a std::vector<char> especially for raw data (though it would all depend on usage of the data in your application).

Comment: I think this might not work because `s[0]` is the same as `s.data()[0]`, which might point to a temporal location.

Comment: @FireAphis: No. s[0] is not the same as s.data()[0]. The difference is that if the string uses a `copy on write implementation` it has to make sure that the string is unique before it returns a reference. That is why s[0] returns a reference to a char and not a reference to a const char. The reason data() returns a const char* is that the string data may be being shared with multiple instances of string. Thus when you do &s[0] you are guaranteed to have a pointer to a contiguous unshared string.

Comment: I don't think this is a safe approach either, primarily as I believe that `std::string` doesn't make any guarantees about storage being contiguous - ofcourse for such a small block, it probably is, however there is no guarantee (unless this is C++x0), @chrisaycock's approach is safer.

Comment: @Nim: You are correct. I don't believe the C++03 standard guarantees it. But I believe that C++0x does (because they wanted to be able to pass mutatable string to C-Interfaces) and as part of the analysis they did was to look at current implementations and found that no current implementations of the STL did not use contiguous space for &s[0].

Comment: It is indeed guaranteed in C++11.  In C++03 it wasn't guaranteed, but it was impracticable to implement a string any other way, so yeah, everyone made it contiguous.